# Sum of numbers in German format in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum

I have the following data in amount column which is in german format.Is there any way to find sum of these numbers. Thanks in advance.

```
data1: 1.234,55
data2: 56.333
data3: 888.432,44
```

Comment: how did these numbers get into Excel? If they were entered in a German installation of Excel and you open them in an English/US version, then the decimal symbol and the thousand separator will automatically be adjusted to your computer's regional setting. If the numbers have been imported and are showing as text, there are different ways to import and/or clean the data in the same step. Details about how to do that can be posted only when you clarify what you have in front of you.

Comment: The numbers were saved as normal format in database(data1: 1234.55, data2: 56333 and data3: 888432.44). I have to show these numbers in german format when loaded in excel.Then I have to calculate sum of these numbers.

Comment: You are wasting people's time by letting them guess what's actually in your spreadsheet. Post a screenshot where the formula bar is visible and a problematic cell is selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try on `FILTERXML()` formula. For regional setting you may need to adjust dot `(.)` and comma `(,)` in substitute function.

```
=SUM(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A3,".",""),",","."),": ","</s><s>"))&"</s></t>","//s[.*0=0]"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. There are only numbers inside the column without data part.

Comment: Then `SUM()` function should work with substitute.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NUMBERVALUE()`:

```
=SUM(NUMBERVALUE(A1:A3,",","."))
```

You may need to array-enter this if you don't have Microsoft365.